# Bump cookbook version - how?

Tags: chef-infra, knife, cookbook

Recently I have developed cookbook and it has got version 0.1.0.

Then I have added more recipes for this cook. I want to bump version to 0.2.0.

I want to see both version when I do "knife cookbook show test".

Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Change the version in your `metadata.rb` file and then run `knife cookbook upload test` (or use some other cookbook upload tool if you prefer).

Comment: Nevertheless, I'd also like to have a way to do this programmatically.

Comment: Found a small snippet in [knife-flow](https://github.com/mdsol/knife-flow/blob/043c55dd32ce58a40493b9961fd3099f474b0b87/lib/chef/knife/increment.rb#L52) think I'd adapt that in a rake task.

Comment: @StephenKing You can have a look at [`knife-spork`](http://jonlives.github.io/knife-spork/) too

Comment: @Tensibai yes, I know that and it sounds appealing. I just have to get our team on track first to maybe go that one step further at a later point.

Answer (score 1):

Found this lovely alias while searching for an easier way to do the same thing. https://github.com/jonlives/knife-spork/issues/186#issue-77717477

```
alias bump='knife spork bump ${PWD##*/} -o ..'
```

You can also do it without the `${PWD}` bit, but that doesn't work if you are trying to specify major/minor/patch.

`knife spork` is part of the ChefDK so it should be usable on any machine where you have that installed.